# The size of an Undo/Redo action in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, undo-redo

This might be a trivial one, but I did some search and found nothing. So my apologize in case it's already answered and I just don't know the right wording.

When I'm in Eclipse and I undo in the editor, instead of one, the editor goes back several steps. This is annoying because I don't want to undo all those seemingly "grouped" actions.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Thanks